# How to pass reference to an observer to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, observer-pattern

I have following problem:

I have a *MenuListFragment* class which derives from class *Fragment*. *MenuListFragment* has a reference to an observer.  Observer is informed when user pressed a row in a ListView.

How can I pass observer to object of Fragment class. Currently I do it by MenuListFragment constructor.

```
public MenuListFragment(MenuListObserver observer) {
    mObserver = observer;
}
```

Unfortunately my app crashes when I rotate the phone. I know this is because of not having default constructor, but what can I do??

Comment: I can use `mObserver = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMenuListObserver();` it is all in documentation..

Comment: Yeah, or let your your Activity implement an Interface and cast it to that. Aids decoupling

Comment: @MichK if what you have commented solved your problem, you should post it as an answer and accept it